# What does => mean in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am learning node js, and came across '`=>`' several times, however struggle to understand what this means.

Here is an example:

```
app.post('/add-item', (req, res) => {
  // TODO: add an item to be posted
});
```

Do we actually need this in the above example? A simple explanation would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's nothing node-exclusive, it's an [ES6 Arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
app.post('/add-item', (req, res) => {
  // TODO: add an item to be posted
});
```

basically means:

```
app.post('/add-item', function(req, res) {
  // TODO: add an item to be posted
});
```

The main difference between these two examples is that the first one lexically binds the `this` value.

Comment: good answer, but I doubt `lexically binds the this value` means much to someone that thinks `=>` is exclusive to node.js

Comment: Yes @AllTheTime, but this could be usefull for anyone else that is looking for `=>` information. Therefor, I included it.

Comment: Nothing special about it. Lexical binding is a fancy word for static binding which in turn means that `this` doesn't change inside the anonymous function and always points to the object containing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a different way of writing an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log('Hello I am typescript');
});
```

is equivalent to JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Hello I am typescript');
});
```

Comment: it has two different, default return value on one-liners (no { }) and this is kept from the parent context (that's what you want for callbacks all the time most likely and better use regular functions otherwise)